# ImportError: No module named schedule

Tags: python, macos, import, error-handling, scheduled-tasks

I have made a scheduled programme on the osx system and I am trying to run it in the background, I read a different question about it and it said that this should work in the terminal by using this command, I have also tried downloading the modules as a root, nothing changed:

```
python /Users/teddy/Desktop/herumblödeln/main.py &
```

But the terminal returns an error:

```
teddy@Teddys-MBP ~ % Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/teddy/Desktop/herumblödeln/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import schedule
ImportError: No module named schedule
```

Why does this happen?

My code looks like this:

```
import time
import schedule
import docx
from pync import Notifier
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog
```

Running pip freeze returns

```
teddy@Teddys-MBP ~ % pip freeze
asteval==0.9.27
cycler==0.11.0
et-xmlfile==1.1.0
fonttools==4.28.3
future==0.18.2
imageio==2.19.5
kiwisolver==1.3.2
lmfit==1.0.3
lxml==4.9.1
matplotlib==3.5.1
mpmath==1.2.1
networkx==2.8.5
numpy==1.21.4
openpyxl==3.0.10
packaging==21.3
pandas==1.4.3
Pillow==8.4.0
plyer==2.0.0
pync==2.0.3
pyparsing==3.0.6
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-docx==0.8.11
pytz==2022.1
PyWavelets==1.3.0
schedule==1.1.0
scikit-image==0.19.3
scipy==1.8.1
six==1.16.0
sympy==1.10.1
tifffile==2022.5.4
uncertainties==3.1.7
XlsxWriter==3.0.3
```

Results from pip -V and python -V

```
teddy@Teddys-MBP ~ % pip -V
pip 22.2.2 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)
teddy@Teddys-MBP ~ % python -V
Python 2.7.18
```

Comment: Are you referring to [`schedule`](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)? If so, have you done `pip install schedule`?

Comment: yes, and then I thought I should do it for the root as well, perhaps the system files need it too, but nothing changed.

Comment: From your code directory (`/Users/teddy/Desktop/herumblödeln`), can you run `pip freeze` and copy+paste the output into your post?

Comment: Of course. But it still returns the same error

Comment: `pip freeze` should not have returned that output. It should have returned a list of packages you have installed.

Comment: I might have done something wrong, I will check again.

Comment: Yup, my bad, it does return the libraries

Comment: I had the same problem. The problem was I used a different python version for VSCode and the terminal (If you use VSCode), you can try changing the interpreter for python in VSCode. Press cmd + P (mac) or ctr + P (windows), type ">python select interpreter". If more than one python interpreter shows up, try all of them and run your code. For me it worked.

Comment: Other interpreters did not support the other necessary libraries. Perhaps I should try downloading some other interpreter but I feel like there should be a more straightforward way.

Comment: Can you run `pip -V` and `python -V` and post result ?

Comment: @Philippe yup, I posted the results

Comment: Your `pip` is associated with Python 3.10 but `python` is python 2.7. Try `python3 /path/to/main.py` (or, the worst case: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3 /path/to/main.py` if this specific version of `python3` isn't in your `PATH`).

Comment: I think it is in the path. `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages`

Comment: When you type `python`, you are running `python 2.7`, not `python 3.10`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your terminal run `pip install schedule`, your output message should be like `Requirement already satisfied` because you have it installed already, just that you are in a different `venv`.

Now, before `Requirement already satisfied` message you will find a `path`, **copy that that `path`**.

Now go to your `main.py` because that is where the error is found. Before `import schedule` you should `import sys`.  E,g:

```py
import sys

sys.path.append("/past/the/path/you/copied/here")

import schedule
```

Comment: For some reason this returns the following error:                                           teddy@Teddys-MBP ~ % Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/teddy/Desktop/herumblödeln/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    import schedule
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/schedule/__init__.py", line 85
    def __init__(self) -> None:
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You are on the right  track. Remove the `__init__.py` if it is part of the `path` you copied.

Comment: hmm I can't seem to find an issue, nope the path does not have `__init__.py` I tried looking for the path in different locations but I got the same one that for some reason returns that error.. `teddy@Teddys-MBP ~ % Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/teddy/Desktop/herumblödeln/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    import schedule
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/schedule/__init__.py", line 85
    def __init__(self) -> None:
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Can you paste your copied  path here let me see?

Comment: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages

Comment: You first try `pip install schedule` because that is one approach which will take you to the right path where the module is installed, copy the path before the message `Requirement already satisfied` and then append that path in your python file, so it should be like. E,g `sys.path.append("/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages")`