# Import Error: No Module named XXX Error - How can I fix this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror

I am trying to import a package and run it directly using an absolute import, but I get an error that the module does not exist. However, in my file display, it shows up at the very top. Any advice on how to fix this?

This is what I am currently doing:

```
from BioModelsDAG.pipeline.bases import BaseParser
```

[image: File Path Directory]

Traceback error:

```
(CSE160) wfh@sadias-MBP BioModels-DAG % /usr/bin/python3 /Users/wfh/Documents/BioModels-DAG/BioModelsDAG/pipeline/parsers
/derived_model_parser.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/wfh/Documents/BioModels-DAG/BioModelsDAG/pipeline/parsers/derived_model_parser.py", line 1, in <module>
    from BioModelsDAG.pipeline.bases import BaseParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'BioModelsDAG'
```

Let me know if I need to provide more information.

Comment: BTW, if no one's mentioned it already, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Python doesn't know where that module is.  If you insist on having your test file be part of the module, then you need to add that directory to the Python path, by doing something like `import sys` / `sys.path.append( os.path.dirname(__file__)+'/../../..')`  Either that, or move the module into your Python `site-library` folder.

Comment: got it. where/what is the python site-library folder?

Comment: how do i move my module into my python site-library folder

Comment: You can try this>> [File not found Error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73347177/19290081)