# pytest cannot import module while python can run the code

Tags: python, pytest, python-poetry

I am working on a project in Python.
I used poetry to install the dependencies and (try to) run the tests.
The code runs in a docker container.
I'm using the interpreter for the venv.

My problem is that I keep getting this error:

```
ImportError while importing test module '/Users/kenny/Documents/GitHub/dash-cass/tests/test_routes/platform_test.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
test_routes/platform_test.py:3: in <module>
    from dash_cass.main import app
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dash_cass'
```

This is my code structure.

```
>dash-cass
    >src
      >dash_cass
          >database
             __init__.py
             platform_component.py
          >routes
             __init__.py
             platform.py
          >schemas
             __init__.py
             requestschemas.py
             tableschemas.py
          __init__.py
          conftest.py
          main.py
     >tests
        >test_routes
           platform_test.py
           __init__.py
        __init__.py
     pytest.ini
     .env
```

I've already tried to play around with the **init**.py, try to use: `python -m pytest tests/` and `poetry run pytest` (run in tests folder).
I've also tried to add the path to the .env and the conftest.py with no luck.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Did this answer your question? [No Module found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73347177/19290081)

Comment: @JamiuShaibu I don't think so, my problem is not a dependency, but that I cannot import main and the other components

Comment: Your main in is **>schemas** directory and that is where you should import from, not **>dash_cass**.

Comment: @JamiuShaibu I will edit it. main is in the dash_cass

Comment: Sorry, your **main.py** is rather in **routes** directory. So I just posted an answer.

Comment: @JamiuShaibu  Just edited the dir structure. It's in the dash-cass

Comment: __init__.py, conftest.py, main.py are on the same level of schemas, they are in the dash cass folder. routes and schemas only contains platform and some schemas.

Comment: Ah yeah I see. You are right on that. So what you need is the  path to **dash_cass** folder. Get the path and insert it in the code I provided below and then import main.

Comment: Please share your `pyproject.toml` and the complete folder structure of the project as well. Did you run `poetry install` at least once?

Answer (score 0):

Copy the **path** of your **dash_cass** folder and insert it into your working directory

```py
import sys

sys.path.insert(1, '/paste/dash_cass/path/here')

import main
```