# unable to download pygame module in python

Tags: python, module

I am a beginner in python , I want to download a module named pygame , I was told to type pip install pygame in the command prompt , I did it , now when I went back to vscode , and run "import pygame" , It says No module named 'pygame'

Comment: Can you check your python version and pip version ? You can also try `pip3 install pygame` . It's possible that you have mutliple versions of python installed on your computer and vscode might not be using the one you installed pygame to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named schedule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73347177/19290081)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things you should check :

1. In terminal (cmd), type `pip list` and check if pygame appears in the list
2. In terminal (cmd), if you type `python`, which version of python shows up ?
3. Check your system path to see where your default python is store on your computer
4. On vscode check if you are using the right python interpreter. Go to vscode do `ctrl + shift + p`. A search window will appear, type `python interpreter`. You should see an option name `Python: Select Interpreter`, click on it and if you see multiple python interpreter here you can just try them and see if it solve the problem.
5. You can try to replace `pip` with `pip3` in all your pip commands and see if it works but sooner or later you will need to take a deeper look on how everything is set up on your computer, this will prevent you some headache along your developer journey
6. If you are lost and nothing works, I would simply suggest uninstalling python all together, make sure you've uninstall every instance of python on your computer and reinstall it from scratch. Make sure you check "Add to PATH" while installing
7. You can also look at virtual environement but if you are just starting out with coding and everything related to that, it might be a little too advance especially on windows (if you happen to be on linux this might be a solution it's really easy to set up on linux)

Comment: I typed pip list in cmd prompt and pygame was present and my python version is 3.10.6

Comment: I'm almost sure your vscode is not using the right python interpreter : Go to vscode do `ctrl + shit + p` a search bar will appear, type `python interpreter` you should see a `Python : Select interpreter` option click on it and see if there are mutliple interpreter here. It so you can just try them all and see if it fix your problem

Comment: No worries :) If it solve your issue, can you please mark the anwser as accepted ? Have a good day